# Run a shell script in Terminal through a keyboard/desktop shortcut

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, minecraft

I'm using Linux (Mint 20.3) to run a simple Minecraft server and I want to be able to start the server with a keyboard or desktop shortcut. I also want to be able to interact with the server in a terminal after it starts. I'm currently using the server software supplied by Mojang. I wrote a little program to get things started:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/trevor/Minecraft_Server
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./bedrock_server
exec $SHELL
```

I can get the server to run but I have no clue how to get it to open a terminal window so I can interact with the server. I'm relatively new to Linux so any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use screen to detach and attach to run commands into the minecraft terminal.

to install screen:
`apt-get install -y screen`

To launch, update your script with something like:
`screen -S mcs ./bedrock_server`

to reattach, run the following in a terminal:
`screen -r mcs`

Comment: Where would I put "screen -S mcs ./bedrock_server" in the script? I tried putting it in at the end and before LD_LIBRARY and when I tried to reattach, it said there were no screens to resume.

Comment: I think you may be missing running the java vm?

Answer (score 0):

Use `screen` in your script to reattach to bedrock process.

Install `screen`:

```
apt-get install screen
```

Define your script as:

```
#!/bin/bash
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
cd /home/trevor/Minecraft_Server
screen -d -m -S bedrock ./bedrock_server
```

After invoke your script, screen creates a socket that can be used to reattach to your script terminal. You can show screen sockets available with:

```
screen -ls
```

Parameter `-S` defined 'bedrock' as the socket name. So you can open another terminal as you like and reattach to the bedrock process with:

```
screen -r bedrock
```

If you detach the screen with `CTRL+C` the screen will be closed and so the minecraft bedrock server. To deattach without close the process you must use `CTRL+A and CTRL+D`.